Archiver to backup a changing directory
So there is a directory that is actively changing. I want a backup snapshot, but both tar and zip crash as a file is deleted or changed while they read it.
Is there any archiver in Linux-world that would, in this case, just skip the affected file and continue with  the rest?

Use tar --ignore-failed-read ... when compressing. Should fix the problem.

Can you not stop the service(s) that are writing to the directory, start and complete the backup, and restart the service(s)?

You have a consistency problem. tar et al. erroring out/ complaining about that is just so you know that you'd be producing a broken backup!
The only way to address this properly would be capture a consistent state of the directory. What good is a backup if half of the files in it are half-overwritten with something different?
But for that, you'd need to stop whatever is currently changing files. (Note: usually, software in such situations doesn't open existing files and overwrites their content, but creates a new file with a temporary name, and then rename2s that file to the name of the existing file, which atomically replaces the whole file. You could then back up all files in a directory safely, if you ignore the files with the temporary names.)
So: Fix the software that is currently overwriting your files, or you can't have a consistent backup.
Assuming you want a backup with minimal breakage, you'd really want to do your snapshotting at the filesystem level (you can then make an archive  out of that snapshot of the directory). That way, at least you only have broken the files that were currently written while doing the snapshot (which is quick), not the chance to break all files that get change while you're building the archive (which takes longer).
For that, you need a file system that supports snapshots – on Linux, that's currently (realistically) ZFS or BTRFS. But these are pretty good choices for your type of workload, anyways, so that's not really an obstacle.
You can then just use the filesystem tools to make a snapshot of the directory exactly as it is in the very moment of taking the snapshot. What you then do with the snapshot is your choice – most probably, you'll want to take an incremental backup of that and move it to a different machine.
I'd roll with something like:
#!/bin/sh
directory=foobar
## ONLY ONCE: PREPARATIONS

# You want your directory of interest to be a btrfs "subvolume".
# That's easy: move the original directory out of the way,
# create the subvolume, move the old contents back in
mv -- "${directory}" "${directory}_old"
btrfs subvolume create -- "${directory}"
mv -- "${directory}_old/*" "${directory}"
rmdir -- "${directory}_old"

# you might want to set up a remote restic repo
# (have your ssh_config such that the login works without interaction)
remote_repo=sftp://mikhail@example.com:/mnt/backups
# put password for backup encryption in this file:
RESTIC_PASSWORD_FILE="/etc/restic-password"
chmod 600 "${RESTIC_PASSWORD_FILE}"
restic -r "${remote_repo}" init

## MAKING A BACKUP
## make a read-only snapshot (uses nearly no storage, quick)
snapshot="${directory}-snapshot"
btrfs subvolume snapshot -r "${directory}" "${snapshot}"

## backup using restic, and only if that worked, remove snapshot
( \
  restic backup -r "${remote_repo}" -- "${snapshot}" \
  || -- mv "${snapshot}" "backup-failed-$(date +%s)" \
) \
&& btrfs subvolume delete "${snapshot}" \

